# How to say "changed academic course" in resume?

Tags: words

I'm writing my resume in japanese, and I have a rather unusual cursus as a french student.

I spent 2 years doing my bachelor's degree in IT, then instead of finishing my degree, I changed my cursus entering a 3 years engineering cursus which leads to a master degree in engineering (in France it's called "Diplôme d'ingénieur").
In the end I will have a master degree without a bachelor's degree, and my parkour was 5 years long.
Generally, people who go to engineering school spend 2 years after high school to study intensively in order to pass an entrance exam for 3 year cycle "Grandes Ecoles" (or in my case engineering school).

I wonder how to write it in Japanese, is it how my resume looks so far but I've been told that what I wrote is wrong:

[image]

So I'm not sure what term I should use in 2013/7

Comment: ^ 「[終了]{しゅうりょう}見込み」 →「 [修了]{しゅうりょう}見込み」です・・・（漢字が。）

Comment: @chocolate IMEの問題だった！

Comment: What does "cursus" mean? I'm having trouble finding the meaning of that word (:

Comment: @Locksleyu  cursus = course of study if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

入学 means you enter the school (college, university, whatever), and make a fresh start of studying in that school.

中退 means you dropped out from school in midway, and your record of studying there is not acknowledged as any meaningful carrer.

However, you were able to use your record of studying in パリ第六大学情報工学部学士課程 in entering パリ１１大学情報工学部修士課程.

In that case, you probably finished a full course of パリ第六大学情報工学部学士課程, and you should write so, as パリ第六大学情報工学部学士課程修了 instead of 中退, meaning 'dropped out,' or you may also write パリ１１大学情報工学部修士編入, instead of 入学.

You'd be better to avoid using the word, 中退、which is counted nothing as a career in this country.

Comment: @駑馬十駕. You edited the last word of my answer. By 変な外人、the original word I used, So be it. But in my original wording, I meant a foreigner who speaks strange word that doesn't make sense to locals, which is a cliche refering to a foreigner you're're not familiar with, and it's different from "counted nothing in this country. It might have been a bad joke.

Comment: 編集履歴を見ると、スペルミスしか変えてないようですが…？ http://japanese.stackexchange.com/posts/34251/revisions (< "edited 〇〇 ago"のリンクを押したら行きます)

Comment: I just corrected misspelled words as pointed out by @DariusJahandarie ; nothing more. Maybe your comment was meant to be on another question's answer?

Comment: @駑馬十駕. My great apology. I jumped the gun. It (変な外人) was  in my answer to the question, "良かったでした. Is this correct? Sorry for giving you a stray blow.

Comment: @Darius Jahandarie. Thank you very much for your pointing out my misunderstanding. I'm ashamed of having a lot of misspelling in a bief statement.